# Showing video in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, video-capture

Im new to python. Im trying to display a video in tkinter lable. I found the following code from https://gist.github.com/aj-ames/ef77f30008faf1cbb85ac90aa3851f11#file-tkinter-webcam-py  that displays from webcam.

```
width, height = 1920, 1080
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit()) 
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack()

def show_frame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, show_frame)

show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

But I want to connect to the camera and load video on button click event. So, I modified it like the following. But its not showing the images on the label even though its reading the frames. Please help.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import cv2
from tkinter import *
def connect_camera():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    show_frame(cap)
    return

def show_frame(cap):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        print("test")
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lbl.imgtk = imgtk
        lbl.configure(image=imgtk)
        root.after(10000, show_frame(cap))


width, height = 1920, 1080
root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+0+0")
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="Connect to camera", command=connect_camera)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `root.after(10000, show_frame(cap))` to `root.after(10000, show_frame, cap)`. Also is it really supposed to run every 10 sec? The 10000 is in ms.

Comment: @TheLizzard God bless you. It worked.